# Why is my chicken blue?

Tags: stardew-valley

I just bought a chicken from Marnie and to my surprise when I checked my coop it was blue! Is something wrong with it?

Comment: Maybe it's cold?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I would have said drunk, but i guess your option works too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After reaching 8-hearts friendship with Shane, all chickens you acquire have a 1/4 chance of looking blue. Other than appearance they're exactly the same as normal white chickens.

Comment: What? Why? . . .

Comment: There's a cut-scene with Shane where he talks about devoting his time to the chickens and producing the best eggs in the valley. During this scene he has some blue chickens. I'm assuming the blue chickens you get are just a call-back to this scene.